# Problems with function detecting Date Value on Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm coding a function that returns true in A6 if any new value is entered on row 4 is a Date and false on the other side. But it returns all false, even I enter a Date value or any other value. Can anybody show me my mistake.

```
function isValidDate(d) {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
    return false;
  return !isNaN(d.getTime());
}
function onEdit(e) {
  ss2 = e.source;
  chanr = e.range.getRow();
  chancl = e.range.getColumn();
  vlnhap = e.value;
  oct = ss2.getActiveSheet().getRange(chanr,chancl).getCell(1,1);
  if(chanr === 4){
if(isValidDate(oct)){
  ss2.getActiveSheet().getRange('A6').setValue('true');
  }
else{
  ss2.getActiveSheet().getRange('A6').setValue('false');
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use: `=DATEVALUE(A1)` ?? Wrap it like this to get the true/false: `=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A1)),false,true)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular functions? Try this in A6:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(
  FILTER(4:4,4:4 <> ""))),false,true)),false)
    > 0,false,true)
```